Why do many developers use 3rd party provider for notifications instead of rolling their own?
I have built many desktop, mobile and web apps, but have never needed to implement push notifications, now I'm working on an app that requires push notifications, researching revealed that many projects/developers use 3rd party providers for push notifications like FCM, Onesignal, Twilio or pusher.
so my question is:
why do developers prefer to use these services instead of writing a custom notification pusher ?
for example i am using Laravel for the backend, which has a performant websocket server that can be used for notifications very easily, so if I'm writing the backend anyway, why not just add a few more lines to implement the notifications part?

Web sockets only help you while the browser tab is open. So that's insufficient for push notifications. On mobile devices, custom notification systems also tend to consume more battery and are less reliable than the built-in service provided by Apple/Google.

Nothing is opinion based in this question or answers. Please reopen.

The code is not the primary problem. It is about scale, distribution, synchronization, global presence and server resources. You can make it work conceptually but you cannot manage a global infrastructure.

I think the main reason is that there are multiple types of notification and you don't want to deal with them all

browser
android
iphone
windows phone!!
teams?
sms

If you just want one of them, fine you might go through the hoops, but when you "just want notifications!" and you can sign up to a service which handles them all for a low cost, it makes sense to use a third party.
This limits your integration to a single provider rather than a dozen

Battery efficient notifications are impossible without Google's or Aplle's services,  I feel that is as important as variety of platforms to support. Could you add that, so @amon and me could upvote?

not sure i follow? if i send a notification via a third party, that third party will use apple/google/whatever

The important part is not to raw-dog websockets or equivalent.

I love the way you can use "raw dog" in any context these days :)
